# How to select data from array of reference ID in php or mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Our table

```
|id | team_id |

|1 | 2,3 |

|2 | 3 |

|3 | 3 |

|4 | 4,3 |

|5 | 2 |
```

............

We want to show all records where team_id = 3.
So I want to show 1,2,3,4 ID as output.

Please tell me how to make query for this.

Comment: What did you try already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id) FROM `your_table_name` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(3,team_id );
```